# \align does not work

Tags: align

```
\begin{align}

At most \euro 2 million should be invested in renaissance

\\

At least \euro 1.5 million should be invested in modern art

\\

The investment in contemporary art should be at least half of the combined total investment in renaissance, neoclassicism and romanticism

\\

The combined total investment in renaissance and contemporary art should be at most \euro 5 million

\end{align}
```

I probably made an elementary mistake but this is what I get:

[image]

Obviously, I’d like them to be aligned and numbered. 
If anyone knows what I did wrong please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment `align` is meant for typesetting math.

Since you said something about numbering, you probably want something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
    \item At most \euro 2 million should be invested in renaissance
    \item At least \euro 1.5 million should be invested in modern art
    \item The investment in contemporary art should be at least half of the combined total investment in renaissance, neoclassicism and romanticism
    \item The combined total investment in renaissance and contemporary art should be at most \euro 5 million
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`align` is `amsmath` construction for aligning math. You are probably have in mind `flushleft` (or `flushright`):

```
\begin{flushleft}
At most \euro 2 million should be invested in renaissance
\\
At least \euro 1.5 million should be invested in modern art
\\
The investment in contemporary art should be at least half of the combined total investment in renaissance, neoclassicism and romanticism
\\
The combined total investment in renaissance and contemporary art should be at most \euro 5 million
\end{flushleft}
```

Please observe that `\\\\` are changed into `\\`'s. If you need larger vertical skips, you can use, say, `\\[10pt]`.